# Can't find file specified when trying to start a process

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a C# app that will connect to a file share, write to a file, then disconnect.

```
NetUseCmd = "net use t: \\Hostname\Vol /user:UserName SomePass"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(NetUseCmd);
Directory.CreateDirectory(DriveLetter + ":/" + DirName);
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(DriveLetter + ":/" + FileName);
file.Write(logdata);
file.Close();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net use " + DriveLetter + ": /del");
```

On the second line of this, I'm seeing the error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  Message="The system cannot find the file specified"
  Source="System"
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=2
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
       [...]
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I know the error message means it's not finding the net command, but I don't get why it isn't finding it.

Comment: I would use Path.Combine, but that may not be your issue.

Comment: Trying to understand why you do all this just to write a file on a share. Can you explain?

Comment: Steve: Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass some parameter to net.exe you should use another overload version of `Process.Start()`:

```
string arguments = @"use t: \\Hostname\Vol /user:UserName SomePass";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", arguments);
```

Please check your source code for the double back-slash too (without @ it's an escape sequence).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the command to use as the first parameter and then any arguments to pass to the process as the second parameter. So:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "net", "use t: \\Hostname\Vol /user:UserName SomePass");
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) for further details.